# Does interface creates objects if it is implemented by a class?

Tags: c#, interface

If a class instantiated it will create an object.Memory will allocated to the instance. 
What happens if Interface intstantiated? 
Does interface has constructors? Does it create an interface object.does it alllocate memory to interface object

```
interface IInteface {}   
class Test : IInterface{}
```

`IInterface ex1 = new Test();`

what above line will create ?

Comment: Did you try this code ?

Comment: How can we create a reference at this point using IInterface?

Comment: Line you are talking about will create "syntax error" - there is no `New` in C#. Side note: after edit your sample does not related to text/title of the post - your code simply creates an object, while post discusses some non-existent concept of "create an interface object".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for notifying me.. I have edited.

Comment: If interface is not creating an object. How could we point another class object through interface.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces have no constructors and can't be created by themselves.

Assigning an object to variable (including variable of interface type) does not create new object, it is just another reference to the same object.

```
 class DerivedWithInterface: Base, IEnumerable {}
```

Now you can create instances of `DerivedWithInterface` class and assign to variable of any of base classes/interfaces, but only `new` will create an object:

```
 DerivedWithInterface item = new DerivedWithInterface();
 IEnumerable asEnumerable = item; // asEnumerable is the same object as create before
 Base asBase = item;
```

Now you can do casts back to original object and there still will be exactly one (or as many as you've `new`ed up):

```
 IEnumerable asEnumerableItem = new DerivedWithInterface(); 
 DerivedWithInterface itemViaCast = (DerivedWithInterface)asEnumerableItem;
```

both `asEnumerableItem` and `itemViaCast` refer to the same single instance of and object of type `asEnumerableItem`

Answer (score 4):

Interfaces are abstract concepts that *cannot* be instantiated. They serve to define a contract for implementing classes to fulfill.

Then, you can create instances of concrete classes implementing the interface (usually with `new`), and use an interface *reference* to point to *that* instance.

Comment: If interface is not creating an object. How could we point another class object through interface.?

Comment: Is it possible to access class properties thorough interface type reference variable?... Because interface don't have variables.

Comment: In C#, you can have properties in interfaces, so you can access them from an interface reference. In Java, you can use getter and setter methods in interfaces for the same purpose. But since fields cannot be declared in interfaces, you cannot access any fields through interface references. Note that an interface reference can only access the members declared in the interface, and not any new members added in the implementing class. To access instance members that are not declared in the interface, you'd need to downcast or use reflection.